# Data Read Concurrency - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a procedure that is called by several users at the same time, this process is a data conference that the client runs 24x7, so this procedure aims to list all records that are not in work ordered by registration date.

For each call the procedure returns a single `TOP (1)` record.
When this record is returned, it is also updated in the table, receiving the current date, and is "stuck" for an hour to work, if the user does nothing with this record, after an hour, the record can be selected by another user .

For that I'm using the hints `(ROWLOCK, READPAST)` in the `UPDATE` statement.

But I receive reports that the data is different from the order of the registration date.

This is my procedure:

```
CREATE TABLE #ProximaConferencia 
(
    PreAutuacao_CodigoProcesso  BIGINT,
    Conferencia_RowVersion      BIGINT,
    Conferencia_DataHora        DATETIME,
    Conferencia_Local           VARCHAR(100),
    Conferencia_MedicaoRealizada DECIMAL(8,2)       
);

WITH PROXIMA_CONFERENCIA AS 
(
    SELECT TOP (1)
        PreAutuacao_CodigoProcesso = CONFERENCIA.CodigoInfracaoPreAutuacao,
        Conferencia_RowVersion = CONFERENCIA.RowVersion,
        Conferencia_DataHora = CONFERENCIA.DataHoraInfracao,
        Conferencia_Local = CONFERENCIA.LocalInfracaoMunicipioUF,
        Conferencia_MedicaoRealizada = CONFERENCIA.MedicaoRealizada,
        Conferencia_DataEmProcessamento = CONFERENCIA.ConferenciaDataEmProcessamento,
    FROM 
        tblPreAutuacaoConferenciaDupla AS CONFERENCIA WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST)  
    WHERE
        CONFERENCIA.CodigoConferenciaUm IS NULL 
        AND ((CONFERENCIA.ConferenciaDataEmProcessamento IS NULL)                  
             OR (CONFERENCIA.ConferenciaDataEmProcessamento IS NOT NULL 
                 AND DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CONFERENCIA.ConferenciaDataEmProcessamento, GETDATE()) > 60))
    ORDER BY
        CONFERENCIA.DataCadastro
 )  
 UPDATE PROXIMA_CONFERENCIA
 SET PROXIMA_CONFERENCIA.Conferencia_DataEmProcessamento = GETDATE()
 OUTPUT
    -- Pré-Autuação
    Inserted.PreAutuacao_CodigoProcesso,
    -- Conferência
    Inserted.Conferencia_RowVersion,
    Inserted.Conferencia_DataHora,
    Inserted.Conferencia_Local,
    Inserted.Conferencia_MedicaoRealizada INTO #ProximaConferencia;

 SELECT *
 FROM #ProximaConferencia;
```

In the procedure, what defines whether the record can be made available to the user are these conditions:

```
CONFERENCIA.ConferenciaDataEmProcessamento IS NOT NULL AND
DATEDIFF(MINUTE,CONFERENCIA.ConferenciaDataEmProcessamento, GETDATE()) > 60
```

That is, the procedure must show all records that have no value in the `ConferenciaDataEmProcessamento` column or that the time is greater than 60 seconds, ordered by `DataCadastro`

After several executions I managed to register the order of the returns, which indicates a problem in fetching the data:

[image: insert image description here]

In this example, it is ordered by `DataHoraRegistro` (column responsible for the recording order in a support table to understand the situation).

What is in yellow corresponds to the incorrect order of presentation, while what is in orange indicates the correct order to present the data to the user. What can be observed in the image is that the day **2022-06-02** is being presented before the day **2022-06-01**.

My question is how can I control so that the records that are free for use respect the registration order.

I don't know if the way to use the hints `ROWLOCK` and `READPAST` are causing this problem or if there is some other way to guarantee that transaction data is not read and that the data read in the current transaction is blocked.

Comment: You need UPLOCK, not ROWLOCK at a minimum.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking, you need to provide a [mre] i.e. the minimum query and sample data which illustrates the problem. It sounds you are just interested in an order by clause in which case the rest of the info is just unnecessary noise.

Comment: The order is not determined by the table - tables have no order.  Your procedure is not returning the data in a specific order because you haven't specified an ORDER BY on the select statement that is returning data to the client.

Comment: @SMor As the procedure is used every second, using UPDLOCK some executions don't return any data, causing problems due to lack of return, that's why I'm using ROWLOCK and READPAST

Comment: @DaleK sorry, I'm starting to work with SQL Server, and the situation is a little complex, I tried to illustrate as best I could, but I think I couldn't be clear. The image indicates a list of executions, the execution of the procedure returns only 1 record and the ordering is in the UPDATE. My question is if the hints I'm using and the way I'm using it is what is causing the selection of data different from the expected order, in the image day 2 is before day 1.